# How do I get a collection (or a stream) of distinct IP addresses using Tor?

Tags: proxy, ip, ip-address, web-crawler, tor

I'm writing a web crawler for academic research. This crawler makes millions of requests that I want to distribute over ten or so IP addresses.

My machine has one IP address already. I can get a second by using Tor.  Can I get even more IP addresses out of Tor?  Here are ideas (and questions surrounding them) that I have for doing this

- Run multiple instances of Tor; each provides an IP address. (But will Tor map more than one or two anonymized IP addresses to my machine?)
- Run one instance but for each request change its identity. (But will Tor rate-limit this behavior, as mentioned [here](http://ge.mine.nu/tor-ctrl.sh.html)?)

Would either of these ideas work, or do the bits in parentheses make them fail?  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tor relays have rate limits](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay.html.en). [NEWNYM is limited to 5 second intervals.](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/394)

If they're not fast enough, a willing botnet or [app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591384/ip-address-block-of-appengine-servers) should work.

Comment: Can you update your answer with a link to some Tor documentation which describes rate-limiting?

Comment: Your given link says "SETCONF bandwidthrate=100kb". I don't know how fast you want to crawl, but basic ddos protection seems mandatory for servers. Indeed, heavy traffic clogs the tubes: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/research-problem-adaptive-throttling-tor-clients-entry-guards

Comment: Actually, I'm not worried about limits related to bandwidth.  I want to know about limits related to the number of new IP addresses (identities) I can take on.  The page that I link to mentions a rate-limit related to this activity, but I have not seen official confirmation of that claim anywhere, also not in the documentation that you linked to.

Comment: In that case, it appears to be limited to 5 seconds: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/394