# gae urlfetch local vs uploaded

Tags: google-app-engine, http-status-code-403, urlfetch

The problem is that, when I do a POST request with urlfetch.fetch(...) in development environment (local server of google app engine), I get HTTP 302 status, as I expect (I can do a redirection). But when I upload the app and try to run it from .appspot.com, then fetch responses with 403, that is "forbidden".

Details:

- url is https (my bank site)
- there are cookies in request headers
- .. what else ?

It looks like, the remote site (bank) sees that 2 requests differently: local is OK, "from goole" is not OK.

My python code:

```
    url1 = "https://www.ebgz.pl/detal-web/jbank/unlogged/choose/method.do?rid="+str(random.random())+"&srvc="       
    response = urlfetch.fetch(url1)

    lparser = Link_HTMLParser()
    lparser.feed(response.content)
    url2 = "https://www.ebgz.pl" + lparser.frameSrc

    hdrs = {}       
    hdrs['Referer'] = url1

    cookie = response.headers.get('Set-Cookie')
    if cookie:
        hdrs['Cookie'] = cookie

    response = urlfetch.fetch(url2, headers = hdrs)
```

Where Link_HTMLParser is simple parser for getting frame's source link (if You look at the first response content of url1 it become clear):

```
    class Link_HTMLParser(HTMLParser):
        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
            if tag == "iframe":
                for n,v in attrs:
                    if n == 'src':
                        self.frameSrc = v
```

The problem is with the 2nd response: its 403 from google, and 200 from local gae serwer.
I mentioned about a POST at the beginning of my question, but it appears that the problem occurs regardless of the method (GET or POST). It's some session management issue I guess..

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's theoretically possible that the bank do not permits requests from some locations (by IP address). And obviously you could ask the bank, whether there are any restrictions.

Note that [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) says about 403 response:

> If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity.

So probably there are some more details in bank's response.

Also you can set up your own service, use it instead of your bank's URL and log all HTTP headers. POST to this URL just like you POST to the bank and compare, is there some other difference in the request from your local machine and "from google", except the request address.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  The 403's explenation is "session closed", like I didn't send a cookie or something like that. Your suggestion for another service is great, and I thought would be a killer-test. But the results didn't point me to solution: 1. There is one gae-special header from google (I don't believe it matters); 2. The google's request IP is interresting: 0.1.0.40. All the rest is the same (session cookie is different by nature). I'll try to post a short portion of code here, so You or anyone interrested could check it out.

Comment: That's strange. Are you sure that the IP address is really 0.1.0.40? It's invalid. Moreover, I've just made a simple test with `URLFetchService.fetch()` and got incoming connection from 209.85.224.95, that is from one of the ranges, given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591384/ip-address-block-of-appengine-servers

Comment: That's strange to me too. I check it with http://2.live-html.appspot.com/req - it prints request details.