# google app engine http requests

Tags: java, android, http, dns, ip

I'm making an application which interacts with google app engine. I'm encountering some time-out problem with it. And this problem is very annoying. Out of every 10 requests approx. 9 time I get this error

```
org.apache.http.conn.scheme.plainsocketfactory.connectsocket
```

Basically whenever I try to post a `http` request `abc.appspot.com` it does a reverse DNS lookup. I think Android has some [problem](http://mailinglists.945824.n3.nabble.com/Android-and-reverse-DNS-lookup-issues-td3011461.html) with DNS reverse lookup.
But we only have different aliases at google app engine & only 1 ip address.

Is there a way to send request directly to the ip of google app engine with the alias `abc`(in this case) so that a DNS query is avoided???

found a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591384/ip-address-block-of-appengine-servers) but not really helpful.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual error code? You have only posted the package causing the error. Or am I missing something?

Comment: write now i'm not getting that error. And I lost the previous one. I'll post as soon as i get. But my question is sending http request to google app engine by ip????