# Google App Engine - list of IP addresses?

Tags: google-app-engine, ip, range, ip-address, whitelist

I know that Google App Engine does not support an application having a static IP address, but I'd like to know if there is a list or range of IP addresses that an app could potentially have? I'd like to use that list as a whitelist of IP addresses for another application deployed elsewhere.

Comment: I don't know much about it, but this is probably what the "Secure Data Connector" is for: https://developers.google.com/secure-data-connector/

Comment: You're going to need to use some other mechanism.

Comment: Why are you relying on the remote IP address? Whitelisting your app will whitelist _all_ App Engine apps. Use authentication.

Comment: @NickJohnson I'm using authentication, but since I also have an option of whitelisting IPs, I'd also like to take advantage of that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IP Address Block of Appengine Servers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591384/ip-address-block-of-appengine-servers)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, GAE premier support directed me to this name, esp as the source IP address for [URLFetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) calls:

```
$ dig -t txt _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com
```

which answers:

```
include:_cloud-netblocks1.googleusercontent.com
include:_cloud-netblocks2.googleusercontent.com
include:_cloud-netblocks3.googleusercontent.com
```

if you then query those, you get this list of ranges (as of 2014-06-26):

```
8.34.208.0/20
8.35.192.0/21
8.35.200.0/23
23.236.48.0/20
23.251.128.0/19
107.167.160.0/19
107.178.192.0/18
108.170.192.0/20
108.170.208.0/21
108.170.216.0/22
108.170.220.0/23
108.170.222.0/24
108.59.80.0/20
130.211.4.0/22
146.148.16.0/20
146.148.2.0/23
146.148.32.0/19
146.148.4.0/22
146.148.64.0/18
146.148.8.0/21
162.216.148.0/22
162.222.176.0/21
173.255.112.0/20
192.158.28.0/22
199.192.112.0/22
199.223.232.0/22
199.223.236.0/23
```

Comment: You made my day / week / month dude ! Thanks soooo much for this ! I was already losing my shits trying to configure VPC & loadbalancers on Gcloud ... This is soo much better !

Answer (score 7):

Use command:

```
 dig -t txt _netblocks.google.com
```

to get the latest google ip blocks, and then you can add the result to your white list.
Be aware that the list are not static and updated from time to time.

Comment: This is only applicable to Google's mail servers. Other services (like Maps, etc.) have different IP addresses than what is listed in that IP4 netblock.

Comment: As of 29.04.2013 there are also requests coming from the following range:

     Level 3 Communications, Inc. LVLT-ORG-8-8 (NET-8-0-0-0-1) 8.0.0.0 - 8.255.255.255
     Google Apps. LVLT-GOOGL-2-8-35-200 (NET-8-35-200-0-1) 8.35.200.0 - 8.35.207.255

Answer (score 5):

From the [GAE documentationn](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#static-ip), you need to use the **dig** command because it does not currently provide a way to map static IP addresses to an application, due to its design:

```
dig -t TXT _netblocks.google.com @ns1.google.com
```

If the **dig** command is not available on your system, you can use an online service:

As the time of writing this answer, querying http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=_netblocks.google.com&type=TXT&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=self&nameservers=ns1.google.com
returns:

```
_netblocks.google.com.  3596    IN  TXT "v=spf1 ip4:216.239.32.0/19 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ip4:209.85.128.0/17 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:74.125.0.0/16 ip4:64.18.0.0/20 ip4:207.126.144.0/20 ip4:173.194.0.0/16 ?all"
```

Here the formatted list for the Google API console if you need it:

```
216.239.32.0/19 
64.233.160.0/19 
66.249.80.0/20 
72.14.192.0/18 
209.85.128.0/17 
66.102.0.0/20 
74.125.0.0/16 
64.18.0.0/20 
207.126.144.0/20 
173.194.0.0/16
```

Please note the IP ranges may change in the future so you will need to run this query from time to time.

Comment: Here's a one-liner to help you parse it: `dig -t TXT _netblocks.google.com @ns1.google.com | grep '^_netblocks.google.com' | grep -o 'ip4:.* ' | sed -e 's/ip4://g' -e 's/ /\n/g'`

Answer (score 5):

I threw this together quickly, for use with the `gcloud create-firewall` command.

```
#!/bin/bash

netblocks=$(dig TXT _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com @ns1.google.com +short | sed -e 's/"//g')

for block in $netblocks; do
    if [[ $block == include:* ]]; then
        ipblocks=$(dig TXT ${block#include:} @ns1.google.com +short)

        for ipblock in $ipblocks; do
            if [[ $ipblock == ip4:* ]]; then
                printf "${ipblock:4},"
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up wrapping the whole thing in a `function source_ranges() {` and then adding `gcloud compute firewall-rules update RULEX --source-ranges=$(source_ranges) ...` Now I just call that in a cron job once a week to keep it up to date

Answer (score 3):

**And this is an updated list as of March 20, 2016:**

Extracted using instructions [in this KB article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/).

```
ip4:8.34.208.0/20
ip4:8.35.192.0/21
ip4:8.35.200.0/23
ip4:108.59.80.0/20
ip4:108.170.192.0/20
ip4:108.170.208.0/21
ip4:108.170.216.0/22
ip4:108.170.220.0/23
ip4:108.170.222.0/24

ip4:162.216.148.0/22
ip4:162.222.176.0/21
ip4:173.255.112.0/20
ip4:192.158.28.0/22
ip4:199.192.112.0/22
ip4:199.223.232.0/22
ip4:199.223.236.0/23
ip4:23.236.48.0/20
ip4:23.251.128.0/19

ip4:107.167.160.0/19
ip4:107.178.192.0/18
ip4:146.148.2.0/23
ip4:146.148.4.0/22
ip4:146.148.8.0/21
ip4:146.148.16.0/20
ip4:146.148.32.0/19
ip4:146.148.64.0/18
ip4:130.211.4.0/22

ip4:130.211.8.0/21
ip4:130.211.16.0/20
ip4:130.211.32.0/19
ip4:130.211.64.0/18
ip4:130.211.128.0/17
ip4:104.154.0.0/15
ip4:104.196.0.0/14
ip4:208.68.108.0/23

ip6:2600:1900::/35
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a ruby script for this exact purpose (super simple, easy to update):

https://github.com/stephengroat/whitelist-travisci

```
Resolv::DNS.open do |dns|
  ress = dns.getresource "_cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com", Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::TXT
  ress.data.scan(/(?<=include:)_cloud-netblocks+\d.googleusercontent.com/).each do |r|
    subress = dns.getresource r, Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::TXT
    subress.data.scan(/(?<=ip[4|6]:)[^\s]+/).each do |sr|
      puts sr
    end
  end
end
```