# Google App Engine - urlFetch address not in _netblocks.google.com

Tags: google-app-engine, ip, ip-address, whitelist, urlfetch

For software I am developing, I need to have a list of external IP addresses that Google App Engine uses for urlFetch requests.  Getting a complete list is proving difficult.

The [accepted wisdom](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#static-ip) as detailed on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149470/google-app-engine-list-of-ip-addresses) is to use the output from...

dig -t txt _netblocks.google.com

...but unfortunately this list is incomplete. For example, my urlFetch requests currently emerge from unlisted addresses:

- US based App:  8.35.201.x
- EU based App:  8.35.200.x

Is there any way to get an actively updated list of external IP addresses used by urlFetch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official advice is https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#static-ip. Note that relying on Static IP addresses is bad, for all the reasons listed on that page.

Comment: Thanks for the link to new documentation, which was lacking at the time of the original post...and yes, IP filtering is highly sub-optimal; but if you have to integrate with a 3rd party system that implements it (unfortunately many still do), then you're forced down this route.  This new doc definitely helps explain what you need to do to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer is:

```
dig txt _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com +short
"v=spf1 include:_cloud-netblocks1.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks2.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks3.googleusercontent.com ?all"
```