# What are the IP ranges for GCE zones?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I need to provide my CDN the IP ranges that I might be using when I create GCE instances.  Is the list of IP ranges by GCE location published anywhere?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We don't currently publish which IPs map to which ranges.  We can and do move blocks as necessary to balance capacity.  However, all Google Cloud IPs are listed here:

```
dig txt _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com +short
"v=spf1 include:_cloud-netblocks1.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks2.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks3.googleusercontent.com ?all"
```

See also:

- [Google App Engine - urlFetch address not in _netblocks.google.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420068/google-app-engine-urlfetch-address-not-in-netblocks-google-com)
- [Compute Engine Firewall for App Engine Url Fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534135/compute-engine-firewall-for-app-engine-url-fetch)

Comment: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/n0531m/f3714f6ad6ef738a3b0a) provides a bash script to resolve all IP ranges listed above.

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider reserving ip addresses and reusing those to start/restart your instances depending on what you're doing.

https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/addresses/insert