# Colaboratory virtual instances IP range?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I would like to introduce Google Colaboratory at our company.
However, for most of our experiment, we would need to access a mongoDB server which uses whitelisting.
Therefore, I am wondering if the virtual instances used by Colaboratory have a specific IP range that we could use?
Otherwise, there is still the possibility to use a local runtime with tunneling to a Jupyter Notebook server like described here: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html
Thanks,
Pascal

Comment: The VM IPs will be drawn from the overall GCE IP ranges. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408818/what-are-the-ip-ranges-for-gce-zones

Comment: I need to do something similar.  A colleague pointed out this question to me.  I'm considering starting a Colab instance in GCP with a static, reserved IP address.  Then I could add that IP address to my DB server's whitelist.  I don't know whether that's feasible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can determine the IP address of Colab notebook using below command.

```
!curl ipecho.net/plain
```

I have seen the Colab IP addresses in the range `35.*.*.* subnet` but this might change.

Comment: Always helpful. Thanks for this generally useful answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an official IP range list from Google.

https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json

Comment: That's a HUGE list!

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be in `34.*.*.*` and `35.*.*.*` ranges.

Here's my experiment with a few restarts.

```
# 35.237.149.168
# 35.234.56.15
# 35.231.231.209
# 35.227.111.90
# 35.221.253.131
# 35.221.207.7
# 35.221.166.62
# 35.204.72.157
# 35.201.227.155
# 35.196.149.235
# 35.194.57.3
# 35.185.124.167
# 34.91.205.101
# 34.80.163.26
# 34.80.152.217
# 34.80.203.85
# 34.74.200.106
# 34.73.212.38
# 34.73.174.186
# 34.73.45.78
# 34.68.222.221
```