# Using NNI inside of Google Colaboratory

Tags: user-interface, web, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use nni (https://github.com/microsoft/nni), a hyperparameter search library, inside of Google colaboratory. This library creates a Web UI to dynamically view the progress of the hyperameter search. The problem is that I can't access this web UI from google colab. Since the experiment isn't started on my local machine but on the google colab server, I know that I can't access it with on the usual "http://127.0.0.1" address; I have thus obtained the IP address of the notebook using [Colaboratory virtual instances IP range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639768/colaboratory-virtual-instances-ip-range), but it still doesn't work ("this site can't be reached").

Has anyone used nni with google colab or has already viewed a web page that is run from a google colab notebook ? I don't know where to start so any hint would be great!

I can give additional details if needed.

Thanks for the help!