# How to solve IP canonicalization on Google App Engine Services?

Tags: google-app-engine, ip, canonicalization

I am using Google App engine with Koa.js frameowork, I want to determine what is the ip address that I can use to access my service so that I can implement a redirect in my application.

I am doing this because seositecheckup gives me an error / warning about this and now I am curious what is the IP address for my service

Thanks

Comment: what error exactly?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149470/google-app-engine-list-of-ip-addresses

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.