# GCP VPC no egress except to google apis

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is there an easy way to configure GPC VPC to block all egress except google apis in case instance must have an external ip-address?

Has google provided a static list of ip-addresses for google apis or is there a more elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

See [Google App Engine - list of IP addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149470/google-app-engine-list-of-ip-addresses) for some useful information about generating a list of the IP addresses that currently fall within Google’s infrastructure:

For example, running command:

```
dig -t TXT _netblocks.google.com @ns1.google.com
```

Produces the following list of Google addresses (One note of caution-  these addresses may change so don’t assume this list will remain permanently valid):

```
64.18.0.0/20 
64.233.160.0/19 
66.102.0.0/20 
66.249.80.0/20 
72.14.192.0/18 
74.125.0.0/16 
108.177.8.0/21 
173.194.0.0/16 
207.126.144.0/20 
209.85.128.0/17 
216.58.192.0/19 
216.239.32.0/19
```

You will need to create a whitelist “allow” egress rule whitelisting the Google address ranges, and ensure you set the rule with a higher priority than your “Deny all” egress rule.

This should allow access to Google resources including API’s, but block all other traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Private Google Access so that instance without external IP can reach Google APIs https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access