# MongoDB and Google Cloud Functions VPC Peering?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, mongodb-atlas

I've having issues accessing MongoDB Atlas from Google Cloud functions. It is giving me error regarding IP Whitelisting but I've added both (Serverless VPC Access) IP address range and VPC Network Peering IP address range to MongoDB whitelist.

I've also created MongoDB peering with google cloud.

If I allow (access from anywhere) then my mongodb starts working fine, otherwise it gives error regarding IP whitelisting.

I'm not sure what else I should add to MongoDB whitelist when I've added both IP's already.

Can anyone help me regarding this? A simple step by step guide will mean a lot. (images/video can help big if possible)

****Edit**

I took **(Atlas GCP Project ID & Atlas VPC Name)** to create **(VPC Network Peering)**.
And they both are (Active & Available).

[image]

[image]

And after that I created **(Serverless VPC Access**).

[image]

And added it to my function inside **(connection)**, a function that will connect to mongoDB to get data. It works fine if I set mongoDB to (allow from everywhere) but do not work without it.

[image]

And after that I added **all 3 IP's/CIDR blocks** to the IP Whitelist.

- The CIDR Block from MongoDB Atlas as in 1st image.
- And CIDR Block from Serverless VPC Access.
- And CIDR Blcok from VPC Network as well just like all above.

But I've still confused that when I run this function it still gives me error about IP Whitelist and only works if I allow traffic from everywhere in mongoDB.

Don't know what I'm doing right and what I'm doing wrong. As there aren't any videos available on internet to achieve this.

I even tried this article but still nothing works out.

https://medium.com/better-programming/connecting-google-cloud-functions-with-mongodb-atlas-499a0a82ccf3

This is the error I'm getting.

[image]

Comment: Is MongoDB Atlas in your VPC? If not, whitelisting VPC private IP addresses will not work. Edit your question with details.

Comment: You talk about serverless VPC access, Peering, and public IP whitelisting. Can you detail more precisely your architecture? Do you use Cloud NAT? Do you use private IP to connect to MongoDB Atlas? What is your egress configuration on your Cloud Function? Please, more details!

Comment: I just updated the question with more information, let me know if you guys need more detail. I really need help with this because I'm stuck with this for about 24-48hrs.

Comment: Did you whitelist the CIDR-range you set for the VPC-access-connector? Both in Atlas and GCP?! I think that's what you meant with "And CIDR Block from Serverless VPC Access", but wasn't sure. I wrote an answer for App Engine once. Maybe there's some info that will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66446153/4341096

Answer (score 1):

If you know you need to whitelist specific IPs:

- Whitelist all IPs.
- Connect successfully.
- Download server log.
- Figure out which IP the connection came from.
- Whitelist that IP.

Verify this IP is in your expected range, etc.

If you know you don't need to whitelist specific IPs:

- Reference Atlas documentation that says so and explains how VPC peering is supposed to work (medium posts are not a substitute  for official documentation).

If you don't know whether specific IPs need to be waitlisted:

- Follow the first procedure and whitelist your IPs.
- Then look for official documentation stating what the proper usage would be.

Comment: I'm hosting my cloud functions in (us-central1) region and I've whitelisted CIDR block of that region, I've also whitelisted CIDR block of atlas cloud and CIDR block of my cloud function. Now, I've no idea what IP's are left for me to whitelist.

Comment: The ones that are being used, per the server log.

Comment: Server logs from mongoDB side or Google Cloud side?

Comment: MongoDB server log.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, and ultimately discovered that I needed to use a private connection string rather than a standard one.

from the official documentation:

`You must add your VPC CIDR block address (or subset) associated with the peer VPC to the IP access list before your new VPC peer can connect to your Atlas cluster. When connecting to your cluster, you must use the new private connection strings to utilize the peering.`

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-vpc-peering/

Private connection strings examples:

```
mongodb://xyx456-shard-00-00-pri.ab123.mongodb.net:27017
mongodb+srv://xyx456-pri.ab123.mongodb.net
```