# VPC peering problems from GCP App Engine (nodejs, standard environment) to Mongodb Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-app-engine, mongodb-atlas, vpc

**EDIT - SOLVED**

as mentioned in comments here is a link to follow IP whitelisting process and check your IP's that work with VPC:
[MongoDB and Google Cloud Functions VPC Peering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64945739/mongodb-and-google-cloud-functions-vpc-peering/64950407#64950407)

There are 2 things I had to fix additionally:

1. Don't forget to change connection string to private as indicated here (https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/faq/connection-changes#std-label-connstring-private). There is no mention of that in VPC peering configuration in Atlas docs.
2. In GCP in VPC peering configuration disable option that is checked by default: Export subnet routes with public IP. After that your IP in mongodb to whitelist is in range from VPC serverless connector.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I tried to create VPC peering connection from my App Engine on GCP to Mongodb Atlas. App Engine app is node / react app that is working fine with whitelisted 0.0.0.0 in Mongodb. Here are steps that I made correctly according to all documentations:

1. I have added peering connection in Atlas and it is visible as available.
2. I have added VPC peering connection in GCP and status is active
3. I have added IP ranges from my GCP project network to IP whitelist in Atlas
4. I have created a serverless VPC connector to use with my App Engine  (standard envorionment) here is a line from app.yaml

```
    vpc_access_connector:
      name: projects/project-id/locations/location/connectors/connector-name
```

5. I have experimented with different IP ranges added to whitelist in Atlas. Both clusters are in the same region and I have included regional range from here:
   https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#ip-ranges

There is a problem because connection can't be made and it is timed out (502 Bad Gateway error in my API service). When I have 0.0.0.0/0 (internet) whitelisted in Atlas everything is working fine.

I was wondering if there are any possible changes that can be made in GCP:

- firewall setup
- exchanging custom routes setup in VPC peering setup
- exchanging subnet routes with public IP in VPC peering setup

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64945739/mongodb-and-google-cloud-functions-vpc-peering/64950407#64950407 for the process to follow.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I have eddited my post to show what solved my problem.

Comment: please add an answer to be more clear about your solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB and Google Cloud Functions VPC Peering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64945739/mongodb-and-google-cloud-functions-vpc-peering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments here is a link to follow IP whitelisting process and check your IP's that work with VPC: [MongoDB and Google Cloud Functions VPC Peering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64945739/mongodb-and-google-cloud-functions-vpc-peering/64950407#64950407)

There are 2 things I had to fix additionally:

1. Don't forget to change connection string to private as indicated here (https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/faq/connection-changes#std-label-connstring-private). There is no mention of that in VPC peering configuration in Atlas docs.
2. In GCP in VPC peering configuration disable option that is checked by default: Export subnet routes with public IP. After that your IP in mongodb to whitelist is in range from VPC serverless connector.